# MongoDB $lookup operation in Mongoose returning empty results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to perform a $lookup operation on a MongoDB collection using Mongoose, but the resulting products array is always empty, even though there should be matching documents in the joined collection. Specifically, I'm using an aggregation pipeline to join a userCartSchema collection with a productSchema collection based on a common field, but the $lookup operation is not returning any documents.

Here's the relevant code:

productSchema=require('../schemas/product-schemas');

userCartSchema=require('../schemas/cart-schema');

const user=await userCartSchema.aggregate([{

```
         $match:{user:userId},
        },

        {$unwind:'$product'},

        {$project:{
          item:"$product.item",
          quantity:"$product.quantity"
        }},
        {
          $lookup:{
            from:'productSchema',
            localField:'item',
            foreignField:'_id',
            as:"products"
          }
        }
       
      ])
```

In the code above, I'm using an aggregation pipeline to perform a $lookup operation on the productSchema collection using the item field from the userCartSchema collection. However, the resulting products array is always empty, even though there should be matching documents in the productSchema collection.

I've tried converting the item field to an ObjectId using $toObjectId, and I've checked that the collection names and field names are spelled correctly. However, I'm still not getting any results.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?